# Very slow Network printing using PrintServer and PrintQueue

Tags: printing, network-printers

I am working on an ASP.NET application and need to send documents to a network printer. I have utilized the PrintServer and PrintQueue to achieve the purpose as follows:

```
using System.Printing;

private void PrintTicket
{
  var server = "Network Server Name";
  var filePath = "File to Print";
  var printer = "Network Printer Name";

  var printerServer = new PrintServer(String.Format(@"\\{0}", server));
  var printQueue = printerServer.GetPrintQueue(printer);

  printQueue.AddJob("New Printing Job", filePath, false);
}
```

The network printer can be found and the print job is executed.

However, the performance is very slow. It took 5-10 seconds to start printing when method printQueue.AddJob() is executed.If the printer is connected to my local machine, there is no performance issue at all.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PrintQueue class you can simply use File.Copy(filePath, printerDestination, true);
I have tried both the options i.e. using printqueue as well as file copy and file copy is much faster compare to using printqueue class.

Thanks,
Arnab